# How to Assign User Privilege Roles in My Parallel Plesk Panel

Tags: php, wordpress, plesk

I have created a WordPress site using Parallel Plesk Panel for the first time.

- Does Plesk Panel support WordPress or do I need any extra add-on?
- Since I am getting a DATABASE CONNECTION FAILED error, I think there is some user role setting that I am missing. Where can I find that Plesk Panel user role setting?

Comment: https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/setting-up-wordpress/installing/mysql-plesk/

Answer (score 0):

Plesk support wordpress and have its plugin to apply but you can upload wordpress files in your domain directory to use it if wordpess plugin not activated in Plesk.

Follow these steps to install it:

1. First create database user e.g. phpMyAdmin ==> Databases ==> Create Database ==> wordpress ==> Collation

Then:

phpMyAdmin ==> Databases ==> click wordpress ==> wrodpress (click ==>check privileges) ==> adduser ==> wp ==> Host ==> Local ==> password (test)

1. In domain root directory there is a file wp-conf-sample.php take its backup and rename it wp-conf.php. set the following attributes to this file:

   define('DB_NAME', 'databaseName');
   define('DB_USER', 'db-username');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
2. Now go to your-domain-name/wordpress/wp-admin and provide information
3. Finally login and enjoy using wordpress

Comment: please vote up or mark answer if this helped you in any case. This pleased me to go a head and work more actively in this community